# actionListener in a4j:support inside anchor tag

Tags: jsf

i have been using actionListener In a4j:support tag inside anchor tag and to buttons on for editing and one for verifying but action Listener called withowt clicking i an using event= onclick

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please try to rephrase your question as it is unclear what you actually want. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Comment: and also read http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for more jsf related things on asking good questions